# User xsl:call-template with value of xsl:param

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm working on some utility `xslt` templates and I would like to make a template in which you can call another template based on a parameter.

What I want to achieve:

```
<xsl:template name="OuterTemplate.AlternatingRow">
    <xsl:param name="Position" />
    <xsl:param name="CallTemplate" />
    <xsl:if test="$Position mod 2 = 0">
        <xsl:if test="$CallTemplate != ''">
            <xsl:call-template name="$CallTemplate"></xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

But I keep getting errors as `<xsl:call-template name="$CallTemplate"></xsl:call-template>` isn't an allowed action.

Is this even possible? Couldn't find much about this when googling.

Comment: I think you need to keep diff name for param

Comment: $CallTemplate does hold the name of template? Can you hardcode your template name and check whether it work?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for one way to do what you want, based on the FXSL library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the XSLT specification the `name` attribute of `<xsl:call-template>` must be a literal qname, it can't be an expression such as a variable reference.

Answer (score 3):

**While the accepted answer of Ian Roberts is correct, it is possible in XSLT 1.0 and in XSLT 2.0 to simulate passing a "function" (template) as a parameter to another function**.

This has been done in the FXSL library for functional programming with XSLT (1.0 and 2.0).

You can read more about the underlying, main idea of FXSL here (for XSLT 2.0): **http://conferences.idealliance.org/extreme/html/2006/Novatchev01/EML2006Novatchev01.html**

And for XSLT 1.0 here: **http://conferences.idealliance.org/extreme/html/2003/Novatchev01/EML2003Novatchev01.html**

The idea is that instead of a template name, we are passing as parameter a node (say `$pFun`) that is uniquely matched by a template that implements the wanted functionality. Thenn in the called template the following invokes the "passed as parameter" template:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$pFun">
 <!-- Any necessary <xsl:with-param> here -->
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Answer (score 1):

XSLT's mechanism for dynamic despatch is xsl:apply-templates and you can find ingenious ways of building on this capability in Dimitre Novatchev's FXSL library.